# drawing over a view shades the view?

Tags: ios, cgcontext

I am creating a custom view to display month and date, and basically this is what it looks like:

[image]

However, I also want to add a small triangle point down just beneath the blue month label on top. So I added the following code in `drawRect`

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 30 - 5.0, 20);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 30 + 5.0, 20);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 30, 20 + 4.0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 30 - 5.0, 20);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0, 118/255.0, 166/255.0, 1.0);
    CGContextFillPath(context);
}
```

This is basically drawing over the white date label to add the small triangle to my custom view, and it does work. But it has an unexpected side effect of shading the date label itself. The effect is as following:

[image]

Also if you zoom in the image you can see that the round corners are also filled in by a black color. It looks like some layer properties are messed up maybe? What exactly is happening?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Is this the exact code are you using? Also, which class are you subclassing?

Comment: Yes this is the exact code I am using. This view is a subclass of UIView

Comment: It shouldn't shade the view. I used those same lines in a sample project and it works as expected. There must be something else. Try forcing `clearColor` as the view background.

Comment: Interesting! Let me try that.

Comment: @djromero that worked! I set `self.backgroundColor` to clearColor and the shade went away. Why is that?